# mysql query in not normalized table with join and subqueries

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I want to query some data of a mysql table (jos_fieldsattach_values) table which makes my brain smoking.

The given table has following structure which I cannot change:

```
id | articleid | fieldsid | value
```

The table holds News dates. 
See: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8f9bf/1

The aim is to output each news Data as Object or array which is in the next five days. The hard part about this is that the table has not fields like "news date" or "subtitle" but saves all content in the field "values". I can identify the kind of data by the value of "fieldsid". F.e Dates will always have a fildsid in (4,7,10) or subtitles will have fieldsids in (14,15,16) and so on. This is extremly unhandy, but as said I cannot change the table structure or the way the data is saved.

My first step was to get the articles which have news within the next five days

```
SELECT 
    articleid 
FROM 
    `jos_fieldsattach_values` 
WHERE 
     value > NOW() and value < NOW() + INTERVAL 5 DAY
```

Output is: 316, 271, 271

The next step is where I have problems:

```
SELECT a.value,b.title, b.id FROM 
    jos_fieldsattach_values as a 
INNER JOIN 
    jos_content as b ON (a.articleid = b.id)
WHERE a.articleid in (271,216) and a.fieldsid in (14,15,16) and value<>''
```

I´m joining jos_fieldsattach_values with jos_content to get the article titles further I know from my first query which articleids have news to show 
    WHERE a.articleid in(216,271)

Where I struggle is how to order or query the data as object. In pseudo code:

```
WHERE 
    a.articleid in (271,216) //  query rows with article ids only
AND 
    a.fieldsid in (14,15,16) as subtitle  // if fieldsid is X it has to be a subtitle
AND 
    a.fieldsid in (4,7,10) as date  // if fieldsid is Y it has to be a subtitle
```

Edit: The Output would be useful as two dimensional array. Something like:

```
Array
(
[2013-08-09] => Array      // fieldsid in (4,7,10, …)
  (
  [0] => News Title 1     // fieldsid in (1,2,3, …)
  [1] => News Subtitle 1  // fieldsid in (14,15,16, …)
  [2] => News Text 1      // fieldsid in (5,6,7, …)
  )
[2013-08-08] => Array
  (
  [0] => News Title 2
  [1] => News Subtitle 2
  [2] => News Text 2
  )
[2013-08-07] => Array
  (
  [0] => News Title 3
  [1] => News Subtitle 3
  [2] => News Text 3
  )
)
```

Where the date is the First Array and the second array has the data title. Each Array and its child array have the same article id.

Thankful for every approach,

Toni

Comment: what is your expected output?

Comment: When you describe the field Assn

Comment: Hi Aris & Peter, I´ve edited the question to show the expected output. The fields are saved from a joomla third party component which i cannot change ;( thank you, toni

Answer (score 0):

Okay, not the best way probably, but it works:

```
// Array for Field Date
$dates = array("4", "7", "10");

// Array for Field Zusatz
$zusatz = array("14", "15", "16");

// Array for Field Typ
$types = array("5", "8", "11");

// Array for Field Beschreibungstext
$desc = array("6", "9", "12");


$rows = array();


// FIll News Array with Data

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
// Filter for wrong date
if ($row{'value'} !== "1970-01-01"){

// if field has date value
if (in_array($row{'fieldtype'}, $dates)) {
    $rows[$row{'value'}] = array(); 
    $datum = $row{'value'};
    $rows[$datum]["id"] = $row{'id'};
    $rows[$datum]["datum"] = $row{'value'};
    $rows[$datum]["title"] = $row{'title'};
    $rows[$datum]["alias"] = $row{'alias'};};

if (in_array($row{'fieldtype'}, $zusatz)) {$rows[$datum]["Untertitle"] = $row{'value'};}; // if field has Subtitle
if (in_array($row{'fieldtype'}, $types)) {$rows[$datum]["Art"] = $row{'value'};}    // if field has kind of value
if (in_array($row{'fieldtype'}, $desc)) {$rows[$datum]["Beschreibung"] = $row{'value'};}    // if field has descripton value
}
```

}